# PHP Date conversion date_create_from_format() not returning expected result

Tags: php, date

I have a string: `30/06/18  (30th June 2018)`

I am converting to a date:

```
$calcFieldDate = date_create_from_format('d/m/y', '30/06/18')->format('d-m-Y');
echo $calcFieldDate; 
Result: 18-06-2018
```

Now I want to add 20 days to the date:

```
$expiryDate = date("d-m-Y", strtotime("+20 days", $calcFieldDate));
echo $expiryDate; 
Expected Result: 08-07-2018
Actual Result: 31-01-1970
```

I am obviously creating a date format which is then subsequently being treated as a string...

Every time I try a conversion, I just hit another road block - is there anyway to create a date that is then treated like a date?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$calcFieldDate = date_create_from_format('d/m/y', '30/06/18')->format('d-m-Y');
echo $calcFieldDate;
Result:30-06-2018

$expiryDate = date("d-m-Y", strtotime("+20 days", strtotime($calcFieldDate)));
echo $expiryDate;
Result:20-07-2018
```

Strtotime() The second parameter is the timestamp

Answer (score 1):

You actually don't need to revert using `strtotime` and `date` functions, you can actually use `DateTime` to simply add dates into it:

```
$calcFieldDate = date_create_from_format('d/m/y', '30/06/18');
echo $calcFieldDate->format('d-m-Y'); // get inputted date

$expiryDate = clone $calcFieldDate; // clone the original date object
$expiryDate->modify('+20 days'); // adjust the cloned date
echo $expiryDate->format('d-m-Y'); // show the adjusted date
```

Answer (score 0):

This will sort your problem.

```
$str="30/06/18 (30th June 2018)";
$arr_temp=explode(" ",$str);
$str_date=str_replace("/","-",$arr_temp[0]);
$dt = DateTime::createFromFormat('d-m-y',$str_date);
$date=$dt->format('d-m-Y');
$new_date=date('d-m-Y',strtotime("+20 days",strtotime($date)));
echo $new_date;
```